# How to show uniqueness of heat equation starting from smooth initial data?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I've heard the following quoted several times, but I can't seem to prove it or find a proof!

Let $u_0\in C^{\infty}(R;R)$ be of at most exponential growth, namely there exists a $C>0$ such that $|u_0(x)|\leq Ce^{Cx}$ for all $x$. Then there is a unique $u\in C^{1,2}(R_+\times R, R$) such that **(1)** $u$ and all of its derivatives are of at most exponential growth AND **(2)** $\partial_t u = \triangle u,\quad u(0,x)=u_0(x)$.

I know how to prove existence, and I know how to prove uniqueness given some integrability or boundedness assumptions. I also know how to prove the above theorem probabilistically so am seeking a nonprobabilistic proof -- any hints/ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Fourier transform? Energy functionals? Fundamental solution? These are the general approaches used to solve your problem.

Comment: @Mattos Don't Fourier transforms and energy functionals require integrability? And fundamental solutions give you existence but not uniqueness (uniqueness is what I'm concerned about)? I may be wrong! Would you mind fleshing out your comment to an answer?

Comment: $u \in C^{2,1}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R_{+}})$ means $u_{xx}$ and $u_{t}$ are integrable. Lets go down a different path though and use the global maximum principle. Assume there are two solutions to the PDE, $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ and define $v = u_{1} - u_{2}$. What is our new PDE in terms of $v$? And what is the initial data for $v$? Also note that $$|v(x,t)| = |u_{1}(x,t) - u_{2}(x,t)| \le |u_{1}(x,t)| + |u_{2}(x,t)| = 2Ce^{Cx}$$.

Comment: @Mattos A function belonging to $C^k(\mathbb{R}^m)$ certainly does not imply it is integrable on all of $\mathbb{R}^m$.  For instance, $f(x) = e^x$ is smooth but not integrable.   Bowdich, the proof you're looking for can be found in Chapter 2 of Evans' book.  It actually requires fewer hypotheses than you are imposing.

Comment: @Glitch You're right, I shouldn't have been doing maths that late at night. I think I got confused with the control condition.

Comment: @Bowditch You can also find your proof [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~vedranso/Math425_Homework5_Solutions.pdf) with information on the global maximum principle [here](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000003363/10_maximumPrinciples.pdf?hosts=).

Comment: @Glitch Mattos Thank you both-- that answers my question! Do you know if a similar result is true for the initial value problem $\partial_tu+\triangle^2u =0$ on the whole of $\mathbb R^d$? Obviously, the above proofs you have mentioned don't apply since $\triangle ^2$ doesn't satisfy a maximum principle -- but perhaps there's another way?